# Can the direction of angular momentum be changed without external torque?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

Without external forces or torques, the magnitude of the angular momentum is always conserved.

**In this context, is it physically possible to change the direction of the angular momentum vector ?**

If so, what are some examples of processes or mechanisms that allow changing the spin axis ?

Comment: What counts as "external"? Do reaction wheels and control moment gyros count?

Comment: Internal torques can only change the angular momentum of parts of the system, not of the whole system. As such, CMGs and RWs produce internal torques

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of external torques with respect to a particular origin, the magnitude **and direction** of the angular momentum of a system are constant (with respect to that origin).  So the most straightforward answer to your question is **no.**

Comment: what of the tennis-racket effect?  There is no torque yet the racket flips because there are non-inertial forces in the rotating frame, although these are technically not torques.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:  In the tennis racket effect, the angular momentum vector of the system remains constant, while the angular velocity vector changes.  The two vectors don't point in the same direction unless they're both aligned with a principal axis.

Comment: hmmm…. I agree with the second part… not so sure about the first part but I will need to review this material.  see https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2243140